Display real-time element from one page to another in same domain using Jquery load
I'm looking for a solution that can extract an element from one of our pages (on same domain) that constantly updates to a new page.
One constraint is the back end web-server that is displaying the element we want is locked to exactly what is displayed, labeled Origin Server. We want to make a more customized page using some of the same elements.
Origin Server (with elements we want to extract): https://proxy.livemadisonalerts.com/
New Page (where we want to display elements):https://livemadisonalerts.com/?page_id=50
We've been trying to use Jquery Load functionality and originally ran into cross site scripting issues so we ran a proxy that allows all to operate under the same domain name.
This is the code we've been messing with.


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<b>test div</b>
<div id="testx"></div>

<script>
$( "#testx" ).load( "https://proxy.livemadisonalerts.com #scannercontainer" );
</script>



I guess the biggest question I have is if this is the best route to go for this situation. We can use iframe but that seems messy.

To avoid CORS issues when fetching data with JS, you need one of two things: either use the same origin (protocol, domain and port must match, which is not the case here, as one starts with proxy. and the other does not), or make the target server respond with an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. That being said, another way would be to handle all this on the backend, by extracting the HTML, and injecting it on the page before serving it to the user
